# Macro selection

Tags: c++

Is it possible to do a macro selection using something similar to this (wrong) syntax?

```
#define FLAG MULT
#ifdef FLAG ADD
   int op(int a, int b) {return a + b;}
#endif
#ifdef FLAG MULT
   int op(int a, int b) {return a * b;}
#endif
```

Comment: I guess you've mean `#ifdef FLAG MULT` for the second condition, don't you?

Comment: Can you describe what your overall goal is? I'm curious.

Comment: There is no a overall goal, I'm just try to learn C++ :)

Comment: That is the overall goal then ;-)

Comment: While this is surely doable, conditional compilation is a tricky thing. If different translation units see the definition of the function (consider inlined functions) and they have different defines you will be breaking the One Definition Rule and causing undefined behavior. There are better solutions for this...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this:

```
#define ADD  0
#define MULT 1

#define FLAG MULT
#if (FLAG == ADD)
   int op(int a, int b) {return a + b;}
#elif (FLAG == MULT)
   int op(int a, int b) {return a * b;}
#endif
```

However, conditional compilation often leads to sadness (typically, the "unused" branch will end up unmaintained, and things will break when you switch back to using it).

C++ offers better mechanisms (run-time polymorphism, templates, etc.) to solve most (but not all) problems of this nature.

Answer (score 7):

```
#define ADD +
#define MULT *
//...
#define FLAG MULT
//...
int op(int a, int b) {return a FLAG b;}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should try to avoid macros as much as possible, and more so to generate different code depending on defines. That is the first step on a path that leads to breaking the ODR and causing undefined behavior.

As alternatives, you can consider just writing the different alternatives, or using templates (assuming that the function has more logic than a plain operation):

```
template <typename BinaryFunction>
int op( int a, int b, BinaryFunction f ) {
   return f( a, b );
}
int main() {
   std::cout << op( 5, 3, std::plus<int>() ) << std::endl;        // 8
   std::cout << op( 5, 3, std::multiplies<int>() ) << std::endl;  // 15
}
```

If you are going to follow the path of macros, then consider reducing the scope of the macros to the bare minimum (i.e. `#undef` them as soon as you don't need them), provide very explicit and unique names (consider adding the name of the component, the file or something alike to avoid interactions: `#define BINARY_OPERATOR_IMPL_FLAG` is much better than `#define FLAG` to avoid name collisions) and then follow the advice in any of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can surely alter the behaviour of a marko depending on a defined constant
f.e

```
config.h
#define MP
#include "other.h"

other.h
#ifdef MP
 #define // your define here
#elif
 // other define here
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either give the macro a value and check the value, or you can change the macro name. That is:

```
#define MULT 1
#define ADD 2

#define FLAG MULT
#if (FLAG == ADD)
    int op(int a, int b) {return a + b;}
#elif (FLAG == MULT)
    int op(int a, int b) {return a * b;}
#endif
```

or you can do:

```
#define FLAG_MULT
#ifdef FLAG_ADD
    int op(int a, int b) {return a + b;}
#elif defined (FLAG_MULT)
    int op(int a, int b) {return a * b;}
#endif
```

I personally prefer hamstergene's answer

Answer (score 1):

```
#define ADD 0
#define MULT 1

#define FLAG MULT

#if FLAG == ADD
   int op(int a, int b) {return a + b;}
#endif

#if FLAG == MULT
   int op(int a, int b) {return a * b;}
#endif

// ...

int result = op(2, 3);
assert(result == 6);
```